# How to authenticate Azure AD with Xamarin Mobile APP

Tags: azure, xamarin

I have an Xamarin.Forms portable project, now only for iOS, where we authenticate against Azure AD with the ADAL library.

It works very well when the user enters username and password.

But now I need to create a version of the app without username/password. I have created a new app inn Azure AD with a App key and changed the app to identify it selves with this app/key.

When testing the authentication class in a console application I got the Bearer token back. But in the Xamarin project I got a Null pointer exception when calling AcquireTokenAsync.

Any here managed to get this working and can point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Hard to know without any code.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better **not** use client credentials flow .IOS and Android apps are public clients and can't properly protect a client secret. You should never store a client secret in your ios app. Client credentials flow isn't suitable for your scenario . The client credentials flow is used by confidential client applications where the credentials can be stored securely such as a web app or service running on a secure server.